# How to solve an unknown syntax error in parser?

Tags: compiler-errors, bison, jflex

I'm trying to parse this piece of code which is written in my desired grammar and i get syntax error everytime. I've checked my code more than 10 times and i could'nt find a solution. The **[PARSER](https://github.com/aligholamee/Chronicle/blob/master/PHASE2_SYNTAX_ANALYZER/YYParser.y)** and **[LEXER](https://github.com/aligholamee/Chronicle/blob/master/PHASE1_LEXICAL_ANALYZER/Yylex.flex)** codes are generated by bison and jflex respectively, since they are long i have to mention a link to my github.
Here is my simple piece of code but it gives me the syntax error when i run the program.

```
program firstProgram
main
{

}
```

Thanks for helping me with this question.

Comment: @rici You're an expert in this field. Could you please help me out with this?

Comment: `statement_list` does not produce the empty string so `{}` is not produced by `block`. (That might be easier to see if you remove all the excess verbiage in your grammar file, as I believe I already suggested.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You must have installed all the preferences of Bison and Lex. After that you have need 2 files before executing your program. The first file having extension ".l" which you declared the tokens and the second file ".cpp" extension would use that tokes to get a desired output.
you can get a clue from my code. Here it is 
[https://github.com/jotpandher/Flex-Bison-task][1]